# D3 Y-Axis Seems Inverted

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to generate a graph based on some data from a CSV file.

My code:

```
    <script>
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 1000)
            .attr("height", 1000);
        function render(data){
            var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data);

            circles.enter().append("circle")
                .attr("r", 1);
            circles
                .attr("cx", function (d){return d[' Monthly Term']})
                .attr("cy", function (d){ return d[' Principal Balance']/1000});

            circles.exit().remove();
        }
        d3.csv("{% static "data/Total.csv" %}" , type, function(myArray){
            render(myArray);
            myArray.forEach(function(d){
                console.log(d[' Principal Payment'] + ", " + d[' Interest Payment'] + ", " +  d[' Principal Balance'] + ", " +d[' Monthly Term']);

            });
        });

        function type(d){
            d.value = +d.value;
            return d;
        }

    </script>
```

Everything "works" but the Y-axis seems reversed.[image]

Not sure if you guys can see the inspection window but the Y-value should be decreasing as x value increases.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your console output, the Y value is decreasing as X value increases.  In an SVG, the 0,0 location is top left.  So a lower Y value is closer to the top of the screen.  Try inverting the Y value:

```
.attr("cy", function (d){ return height - d[' Principal Balance']/1000});
```

Answer (score 2):

As @genestd states in his answer, SVG y coordinates start at the top and increase in value moving down.  Generally, you should be using a d3 [scale](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#scales-d3-scale) to map your **user space** values to **svg coordinate** values.  Looking at the [classic bar chart example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304), you see these lines:

```
var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);
```

Here, the x scale goes from *0 to width* and the y from *height to 0*.  They are reversed from each other because of the very thing you are seeing, x increases going left to right while y increases going top to bottom.  This `.range` call is mapping the SVG coordinates.

Later you'll see this line:

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);
```

This part has now mapped the user space coordinates, saying they run from 0 to the maximum of our data.

You can then use the scales as functions when you plot your point.

In your code it might look like this:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 1000)
  .attr("height", 1000);

var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, 1000]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([1000, 0]);

function render(data){

  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
    return d[' Monthly Term'];
  });

   y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
    return d[' Principal Balance']/1000;
  });

  var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data);

  circles.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 1);

  circles
    .attr("cx", function (d){return x(d[' Monthly Term']); })
    .attr("cy", function (d){ return y(d[' Principal Balance']/1000); });

  ...
```